# Replacing data.table observations; vector approach

Tags: r, functional-programming, data.table

I would like to replace select values in a data.table variable with a new set of values.

```
### Vector of old values I would like to replace
char <- c('one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven')
### Vector of new values I would like to replace old values with
num  <- as.character(1:7)

### Create a data.table
dt <- data.table(a = c(rep(char, each = 2), c('Something', 'Else', ' ', '')),
                 b = 1:18,
                 c = letters[1:18])

### Note the warning, but also that it appears to work as expected
dt[a == char, a := num]
```

I get the following error:

```
Warning messages:
1: In a == char :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In `[.data.table` (dt, a == char, `:=` (a, num)) :
  Supplied 7 items to be assigned to 2 items of column 'a' (5 unused)
```

I am curious, what's the correct way to do this?

Help is appreciated. I do realize that I can achieve the same result with brute force:

```
data[var == 'Seven', var := '7']
data[var == 'Six',   var := '6']
...
```

But, this introduces redundancy into the code, and redundancy can lead to errors...

Comment: Do you expect to reliably replace "one" with "1" and "two" with "2", etc.? Be aware that matching is happening by accident in your example, because the lengths and order of the data.table column and replacement data are already matched.

Comment: you probably want to set the column you are looking to match (`a`) as the `key` to your `data.table`

Comment: Thank you, I have edited my toy example to be more realistic. The toy example now throws the error I was expecting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `data.table` joins:

```
replacement = data.table(a = char, new_a = num, key = "a")

dt.fixed = replacement[dt][, a := ifelse(is.na(new_a), a, new_a)][, new_a := NULL]
```

Comment: `fixed <- setnames(replacement[dt][is.na(new_a), new_a := a][,a := NULL],'new_a','a')` will mean that there is one less vector created (avoiding the call to `ifelse`).

Comment: One comment to perhaps add is that this method requires that 'dt' is also keyed on 'a', in order for the data.table join to behave as expected. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Andreas not quite - this will join by the first column of `dt` if `dt` doesn't have a key, which is why it works on the data in OP

Comment: Ah, thank you Eddi for the clarification! I realized when I first tried this approach that the variable I wanted to modify took on the values of the first column of 'dt' after joining. This is useful to know!